# Lake with capacity of 1000 fish. How long will it take to reach 900?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

[image: Picture of the question from my textbook.]

Here is my work as well. [image: my work]

I always get stuck when I have to do a u-sub and deal with a negative LN. Some help or a strategy for the future please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can show that$$N = \frac{1000}{1 + ce^{-0.2t}} $$ solves  $$\frac{dN}{dt}= 0.2N \left( 1-\frac N{1000}\right)$$ for arbitrary $c.$  that $N = 20$ at $t = 0$ fixes $c = 49.$  now solve $$ 900= \frac{1000}{1 + 49e^{-0.2t}}$$ for $t.$

Comment: Never mind that, thank you! I need to review one more part of my notes for the test, thank you so much for making that reminder!!

Comment: @Jeff, separating variables and all that. but once you have done for a logistic equation you just have to memorize it. it is easy to memorize it by requiring that $\lim_{t \to \infty} = M$ and $\frac{dN}{Ndt}\Big|_{t=0} = k$

Comment: luckily I think I'm done with this part of my test as tomorrow is the no calculator section. Thank you so much.